# Display User Control(WPF) View page on click of a Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

There are many questions in this community for opening the window View on a click of a button just we need to create the instance of the view and use `.Show` and some question are based on  using User Control in Window View.

I am following MVVM pattern to create a WPF application, in the Views I created a file called `SalesView.xaml` which is a `User Control(WPF)` view and by default I set the  `Dashboard.xaml` from the `App.xaml` which is Window View and the project structure is some thing like this:

[image: Project Structure]

My requirement is that I have a button in `Dashboard.xaml` on click of this button I want to open a `SalesView.xaml` which is a `User Control(WPF)` view not a window View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need some short of shell for hosting your user controls. Simplest way is to put them on main window as content instead of a previous one. Or use some framework like [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx).

Normally how I would do it, I would create a class that is controller/view manager. And then pass in to it my view and vm, then the class would bind it and put it into the hosting window.

```
class ViewManager
{
   public void ShowView<T>(object viewModel) where T: UserControl, new()
   {
       var view = T();
       var window = new Window(); // feel free to prelace this simple approach with hosting shell
       view.DataContext = viewModel;
       window.Content = view;
       window.Show();
   }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
new ViewManager().ShowView<MyUserControl>(new MyViewModel());
```